# how tao have more then one user upload image with code below

Tags: php, upload, avatar

this code is limiting me from having more the one user upload an image

```
$ausgabe = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Senden") {
    $ausgabe .= 'Upload compelte:<br>';
    if (isset($_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'])  && strpos($_FILES['thefile']['type'], 'image') !== false) {
        $size=getimagesize($_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name']);
        if ($size[2] == 1
        || $size[2] == 2
        || $size[2] == 3
        || $size[2] == 4) {
```

Comment: its a snippit of the code i think this is the issue, it only allows one user on the site to upload $size=getimagesize($_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name']);
            if ($size[2] == 1
            || $size[2] == 2
            || $size[2] == 3
            || $size[2] == 4) {

Comment: It's difficult to understand the problem you're facing. If the code is limiting you, can you edit it to not limit you? Also, i'm not entirely sure what you mean by limiting you. You might need to provide some more context here.

Comment: All the code you have shown does, is check the POST parameters, and validate that the file is a valid image. There is no connection to any user whatsoever in there, nor any check whether a file might already have been uploaded previously. Whatever your actual problem is - it almost certainly is not with _that_ piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problem was caused by a mistake I did.

The issue ended up being in the `<form>` where `name="max_file_size...` needed to be replaced as `name="file_size...`